# How to set a password security limit in Postgresql?

Tags: database, oracle, postgresql, passwords, plpgsql

In Oracle we can set a password limit like this:

```
create Profile security_pass Limit 
    failed_login_attempts 5
    password_lock_time 1
    password_life_time 90
   password_grace_time 3
   password_reuse_max 5
   password_reuse_time 365
   password_verify_function func_pwd_vfy;
```

But can we do the same in PostgreSQL? I can't find anything about it. Thanks for reading me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a module with the name "passwordcheck" in Additional Supplied Modules.

Have a look at the following link: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/passwordcheck.html

It will work just like PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION of Oracle.
Using this module you can write your own function for password verification.

Disclaimer: I worked for EnterpriseDB.